# Spark View Engine and Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc, spark-view-engine

I'm working on a project that is using the Spark View Engine, and I am finding the lack of Visual Studio support frustrating.

Is there anything that gives C# and Spark Intellisense in the views?

Anything that helps with refactoring? so that if I rename a C# property, this change gets reflected in the View?

Comment: See if [this](http://sparkviewengine.com/usage/intellisense) helps.

Comment: :( That didn't work for me. Plus turning of resharper intellisence, proved to be annoying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using VS 2010 - you can take a look at [SparkSense](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ef944259-fc8a-42e0-838e-f397957e1d11). It's also available within Visual Studio's Extension Manager for an easy install. It has its limitations - but you can try it out and see if you like it.

You may want to check out Robert Greyling's blog post about SparkSense functionality here: http://blog.robertgreyling.com/2010/08/sparksense-gets-its-first-outing.html

Comment: I'm releasing a new version of SparkSense on April 12th so watch this space. It'll include type completion in views rather than just Spark language support.

Comment: Its the 12th - waiting in anticipation.